# Azure WebJob is failing and its asking for windowsazure.storage 9.3 which is recently deprecated

Tags: azure, triggers, package

My Web Job contains TimerTrigger, BlobTrigger and QueueTrigger. I recently updated all the packages.
I replaced WindowsAzure.Storage with Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table

Also, Iam using below packages

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common" Version="11.2.2" /> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue" Version="11.2.2" /> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" Version="3.0.18" /> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="3.0.6" /> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.2" /> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage" Version="4.0.1" />`

Once below line of code is executed
`await host.StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`

web job throwing below exception.

```
fail: Host.Startup[0] The listener for function 'TimerTrigger' was unable to start. 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException: The listener for function 
'Functions.CheckUnreadTenantDataAsync' was unable to start. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified. 
File name: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

Please can anyone help me?